# Check if item in list is empty using a workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

How can I check to see if an item in the list `New Hire Form` is empty using a workflow? I'm confused because the `Field Data to Retrieve` is asking for the `Field from source` which the `Find the List Item` is asking for aswell ( `Field` ) The field I need to check if its empty is `Approved by Supervisor`

[image]

Also, is the recommended way to check if an item in a list is empty? I am creating a workflow variable:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is this workflow running on the New Hire Form? If it is, then change the `Data Source` to `Current Item` in the first dialog box image that you are showing, and then select `Approved by Supervisor` in the second dropdown, `Field from source`.

Storing the field value in a workflow variable, and then using an `if` statement to check that the variable has a value in order to continue with workflow execution is the way to check this properly (you can set the condition in the `if` statement to `is empty` or `is not empty` as you need).